# Git blame in Atom editor

Tags: github, atom-editor

I usually used the Intellij IDEA to edit code but lately I have been testing out Atom from Github. I was wondering if there was any way to display Git blame in the editor. Intellij dose it by right clicking on the line number and clicking "annotate".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this package and it dose exactly what I was looking for.

https://atom.io/packages/git-blame

Comment: It sucks balls; owner doesn't maintain the package and has over 40 open issues. Right now it's broken for newer Atom versions.

Comment: 2018 update: `git-blame` seems to have picked up the development pace again.

Answer (score 5):

If you type CMD+shift+p in Atom, it displays a list of available commands, you can open the command palette and search for "Git blame", the keyboard shortcut is:

```
option + G + B
```

Actually if you check there is a considerable list of commands prefixed as: "Open On Github", when you fire any of those commands, they're opened on the repo website of your project.

Seems the shortcut isn't working for me, but the command is.

Comment: That looks good. Although I'm looking for support for this in the editor also for projects that are not on Github. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just released a new package which renders the line’s author and date in the status (bottom) bar:

https://atom.io/packages/atom-status-bar-blame